# How to convert multiple RGB images in one folder to grayscale in python

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning

Someone could help me please, I want to convert my RGB images in one folder to grayscale at one time. I've been looking for some Python codes but haven't found any. I tried to do as following but it didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.io import imread, imsave
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu
from skimage import img_as_uint

inp_image = imread("C:/RGB/*.JPG")
img_gray = rgb2gray(inp_image)

thresh = threshold_otsu(img_gray)
binary_thresh_img = img_gray & gt; thresh

imsave("C:/Grayscale", img_as_uint(binary_thresh_img))
```

And it gave me following error:

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:/RGB/*.JPG'

Comment: You need to `walk` (!) through the `C:/RGB/` directory and get the image files. The exclamation point means "you can use `os.walk`".

Comment: Not sure if you are practicing your Python skills (which is a worthy cause) or just want to get the job done. If the latter, you can just simply use `ImageMagick` like this from the command line (after backing up your files) `mogrify -colorspace gray *.jpg` and get them all done without any coding.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the list with the filenames with `glob()`.

```
import glob
for filename in glob.glob("C:/RGB/*.JPG"):
    inp_image = imread(filename)
    [...]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and it really helps me out.Just want to honestly I am very new in image processing with Python.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the list of solutions:

```
import os
from PIL import Image

ORIGIN_PATH = "./folder1/"
DESTIN_PATH = "./folder2/"

for filename in os.listdir(ORIGIN_PATH):                                                                                                                                                                
    img = Image.open(ORIGIN_PATH + filename).convert("LA")                                                                                                                                                
    img.save(DESTIN_PATH + filename)
```